# $F : C \to D$ is an equivalence of categories with quasi-inverse $G: D \to C$. Does the pair $(F,G)$ necessarily form an adjunction?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors

**Suppose $F : C \to D$ is an equivalence of categories with quasi-inverse $G: D \to C$. Does
the pair $(F,G)$ necessarily form an adjunction? How would I prove this?**

I think I can use the unit-counit definition of adjunction.
( Let $\eta$ be the unit $id_C \to R\circ L$ and  and $\epsilon$ be the counit: $\epsilon: L \circ R \to id_D$  )

and the fact that $L$ is a fully faithful functor if and only if $\eta$ is an isomorphism.

but I have  no idea how to do this. Any help is appreaciated

Comment: You can generally not arrange both of the isomorphisms $G\circ F\cong\mathrm{id}_C$ and $F\circ G\cong \mathrm{id}_D$ to become the unit and counit of your adjunction, but if you use the pointwise criterion for adjunctions you can arrange one of them to become either the unit or counit respectively. The pointwise criterion for adjunctions is easily verified, and I will say what I mean with it in a comment below.

Comment: This pointwise criterion is this: if $F\colon C\to D$ is a functor and for each $d\in D$ we are given an object $Gd\in C$ and a morphism $\varepsilon\colon F(Gd)\to d$, then if $C(c,Gd)\xrightarrow{F}D(Fc,FGd)\xrightarrow{\varepsilon_*}D(Fc,d)$ is an isomorphism for all $c\in C$, then there is an essentially unique way to turn the $Gd$ into a functor $G\colon D\to C$ that is right adjoint to $F$, with counit $\varepsilon$.

Comment: This has been asked before! See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3975915/r-l-are-left-and-right-adjoint-in-an-equivalence-of-categories?rq=1) eg. Emily Riehl's book "Category Theory in Context" shows you an explicit way to cook up a suitable unit and counit which satisfy the triangle identity. You fix one of the natural isomorphisms, say, $FG\cong1$, and modify the other one $(1\cong GF)$ so that it's still an isomorphism but so that the triangle identity now holds (which, a priori, it may not)

Comment: So if we want to be extremely formal, the data of an equivalence is *not* the data of an adjunction, but given the data of an equivalence we can always create an adjunction involving the same two functors